# Submit form with jquery confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the Jquery Confirmation plugin, but I'm confused on how to submit a form if I click "confirm" button. Here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button[name='btn-delete-akun']").confirm({
    title: '<p style="color:red;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Peringatan!<p>',
    content: 'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus event? ',
    useBootstrap: true,
    buttons: {
      Confirm: {
        btnClass: 'btn-red',
        //how to submit form if i click this confirmation button
      },
      Cancel: function() {}
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$('#yourForm').submit()`

Comment: Assuming there is NOTHING in the form with name or id="submit"

Comment: share the code of form so that proper identify the problem

Comment: it not works @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: <form id="form_delete" action="/manajemen_list_akun/delete/{{user.username}}" method="POST">
                            
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="submit_delete" name="btn-delete-akun">Delete</button>
                            
                        </form>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
buttons: {
              Yes: function () {$('#yourForm').submit()},
              No: function () {}
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will be helpful try this.

```
$.confirm({
    title: 'Prompt!',
    content: '' +
    '<form action="" class="formName">' +
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label>Enter something here</label>' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="name form-control" required />' +
    '</div>' +
    '</form>',
    buttons: {
        formSubmit: {
            text: 'Submit',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            action: function () {
                var name = this.$content.find('.name').val();
                if(!name){
                    $.alert('provide a valid name');
                    return false;
                }
                $.alert('Your name is ' + name);
            }
        },
        cancel: function () {
            //close
        },
    },
    onContentReady: function () {
        // bind to events
        var jc = this;
        this.$content.find('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            // if the user submits the form by pressing enter in the field.
            e.preventDefault();
            jc.$$formSubmit.trigger('click'); // reference the button and click it
        });
    }
});
```

See detail:
https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Use ajax method:

```
$.confirm({
        title: 'Are you sure you want to approve this application?',
        content: '',
        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'myUrl',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        // data stuff here
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        // does some stuff here...
                    }
                }),
            cancel: function () {

            }
        }
    }
    });
```

You can also write the ajax method in formSubmit action.

Comment: i want to send the form to the server

Comment: @Hendra Feb use the $.ajax({}) method for server in action(){} method.

Comment: @HendraFeb use this script in action method
$.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: ctx + "/cardbininfo/delById",
                    success: function(response) {

                         // logic here
                    }
                });